# The multi-part identifier "TextBox1.Text" could not be bound in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm doing a practice project for training; my handler has specifically forbidden paramaterization and security-oriented coding for now, in the interest of getting the basics down. That being said, I've got a gridview on my homepage with a hyperlink field that takes the user to a page where they can edit the row data in textboxes. The row is displayed by the "ProductId" column, as it is autoincremented and unique. The values display perfectly, so I know my query string is fine, but when I attempt to update using the button event, I get an error message that says

*The multi-part identifier "TextBox1.Text" could not be bound.*

for all of my textboxes. My code is below. What am I missing? This is my first rodeo, so it may very well be basic and obvious to an experienced eye.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Sql;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class ViewEdit : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string x = Request.QueryString["ProductId"];
            string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string editQuery = "SELECT CustId, CustName, SicNaic, CustCity, CustAdd, CustState, CustZip, BroName, BroId, BroAdd, BroCity, BroState, BroZip, EntityType, Coverage, CurrentCoverage, PrimEx, Retention, EffectiveDate, Commission, Premium, Comments FROM ProductInstance WHERE ProductId =" + x;



        using (SqlConnection editConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            editConn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(editQuery, editConn))
            {

                SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                TextBox1.Text = dr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                TextBox2.Text = dr.GetString(1);
                TextBox3.Text = dr.GetString(2);
                TextBox4.Text = dr.GetString(3);
                TextBox5.Text = dr.GetString(4);
                TextBox6.Text = dr.GetString(5);
                TextBox7.Text = dr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                TextBox8.Text = dr.GetString(7);
                TextBox9.Text = dr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                TextBox10.Text = dr.GetString(9);
                TextBox11.Text = dr.GetString(10);
                TextBox12.Text = dr.GetString(11);
                TextBox13.Text = dr.GetInt32(12).ToString();
                TextBox14.Text = dr.GetString(13);
                TextBox15.Text = dr.GetInt32(14).ToString();
                TextBox16.Text = dr.GetInt32(15).ToString();
                TextBox17.Text = dr.GetInt32(16).ToString();
                TextBox18.Text = dr.GetInt32(17).ToString();
                TextBox19.Text = dr.GetDateTime(18).ToString();
                TextBox20.Text = dr.GetInt32(19).ToString();
                TextBox21.Text = dr.GetInt32(20).ToString();
                TextBox22.Text = dr.GetString(21);



            }

        }   
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = Request.QueryString["ProductId"];
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string updateQuery = "UPDATE ProductInstance SET CustId = TextBox1.Text, CustName = TextBox2.Text, SicNaic =TextBox3.Text, CustCity = TextBox4.Text, CustAdd = TextBox5.Text, CustState = TextBox6.Text, CustZip = TextBox7.Text, BroName = TextBox8.Text, BroId = TextBox9.Text, BroAdd = TextBox10.Text, BroCity = TextBox11.Text, BroState = TextBox12.Text, BroZip = TextBox13.Text, EntityType = TextBox14.Text, Coverage = TextBox15.Text, CurrentCoverage = TextBox16.Text, PrimEx = TextBox17.Text, Retention = TextBox18.Text, EffectiveDate = TextBox19.Text, Commission = TextBox20.Text, Premium = TextBox21.Text, Comments = TextBox22.Text WHERE ProductId =" + x; 
        using (SqlConnection updateConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            updateConn.Open();
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, updateConn))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the value of the `Text` property of the `TextBox` controls to the query not the "TextBox.Text" as a string:

```
string updateQuery = "UPDATE ProductInstance SET CustId = " + TextBox1.Text + ", CustName = '" + TextBox2.Text + "', .... " + x;
```

**NOTE**:

If the value of the "Text" property was a string the you have to place a `'` on the two sides of the value like in the example above.

Comment: If you have to assemble 22 textboxes to one string I would not recommend using string concatenation. Use `string.Format` or a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Curious, @Zebi, why not string concatenation? Is there a weakness to it that string.Format has an advantage over, or is it just cleaner/more convenient to write?

Comment: @Brazos: Because combining string values generate multiple string instances.

Comment: Another question, if that's alright: when I used the string.Format method, ' var query = string.Format(queryFormat, TextBox1.Text,  '   I got an error message under the 'query' that said _cannot use more than one type in a for, using fixed or declaration statement_, and when I used the way Akram shows above, I show no error messages but the original home page will no longer load; it just says loading forever. What's up with that?

Comment: The optimal one is following the goal of this practice and learn how SQL and the framework itself works. His question and all further comments show that he needs some basic knownledge. For SQL take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: @zebi: And that what all of owr answers provide actualy. However, if you mean he must follow the simplest method then he has to go with my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use parameters to do this. Otherwise you are wide-open for SQL injection.

```
SQLCommand cmd = new SQLCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ProductInstance SET CustId = @CustID WHERE .... ";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as I specified in my question, I was instructed to avoid parameterization in the interest of simplicity. The website is only for practice, and won't be deployed.

Comment: Simplicity is fine for learning, but parameterization is essential for production code. It's an excellent habit to establish and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Your query will be executed as is, `Textbox*.Text` won't be replaced.
You will have to use SQL Parameters or use a string Builder or string.Format to generate your query string.

```
const string queryFormat = "UPDATE ProductInstance SET CustId = {0}, CustName = '{1}', ... WHERE ProductId = {n}";
var query = string.Format(queryFormat, Textbox1.Text, 
                                       Textbox2.Text, 
                                       ..., 
                                       TextboxN.Text, x);
```

Make sure you generate a valid SQL Update query. Something like `CustCity = TextBox4.Text` will fail if Textbox4.Text is a string. You will have to add quotes where needed `CustCity = '" + TextBox4.Text + "'"`

Even if you can not use parameters or ORMs I would recommend you to name your textboxes other than TextboxN.

Furthermore I don't get how this code would work if you are using a grid view? You are only populating one row?

Comment: Thanks, Zebi. Why would CustCity = TextBox4 fail as a string? By make sure you generate a valid SQL Update query, do you mean use the example code in your answer?

Comment: Yes, take a look at some SQL tutorials first and try executing your queries using a database manager tool to learn. If you want to update a field containing a string value you will have to use quotes.